# Equation for the equilibrium constant for the hydration of carbonyls using UV spectroscopy

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, carbonyl-compounds, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I was looking through the literature when I found a paper by Greenzaid et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1039/TF9676302131)] which states that the equilibrium constant $K_\mathrm{hyd}$ is:

> $$K_\mathrm{hyd} = [\text{hydrate}]/[\text{carbonyl}] = (\varepsilon_0^\mathrm{w} - \varepsilon^\mathrm{w})/\varepsilon^\mathrm{w}, \label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$
>
> where $\varepsilon^\mathrm{w}$ is the molar absorption coefficient measured under conditions of hydration, and $\varepsilon_0^\mathrm{w}$  is the molar absorption coefficient of the carbonyl compound in water in the absence of hydration.

(In water solvent, $\varepsilon_0^\mathrm{w}$ usually taken as the molar extinction coefficient in cyclohexane.)

How did the researchers get to the above equation in terms of the molar absorption coefficients?

As $[\text{hydrate}]$ is equal to $[\text{carbonyl}]_0 - [\text{carbonyl}],$ the equation \eqref{eqn:1} turns to:

$$K_\mathrm{hyd} = \frac{[\text{carbonyl}]_0 - [\text{carbonyl}]}{[\text{carbonyl}]}$$

However, the Beer–Lambert law states that

$$A = c\varepsilon l,$$

where $A$ is the optical density, $c$ is the concentration, $\varepsilon$ is the extinction coefficient and $l$ is the path length.

Denoting the corresponding parameters for carbonyl *without hydration* as $A_0$ and $\varepsilon_0$, and the parameters for carbonyl *with hydration* as $A$ and $\varepsilon$, the following can be written:

$$
\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{hyd} &= \frac{[\text{carbonyl}]_0 - [\text{carbonyl}]}{[\text{carbonyl}]} \\
  &= \frac{\frac{A_0}{\varepsilon_0l} - \frac{A}{\varepsilon l}}{\frac{A}{\varepsilon l}} \\
  &= \frac{\frac{A_0}{\varepsilon_0} - \frac{A}{\varepsilon}}{\frac{A}{\varepsilon}} \\
\therefore  &= \frac{\varepsilon}{A}\left(\frac{A_0}{\varepsilon_0} - \frac{A}{\varepsilon}\right) \\
  &= \frac{\varepsilon}{A}\frac{A_0\varepsilon - A\varepsilon_0}{\varepsilon\varepsilon_0} \\
  &= \frac{A_0\varepsilon - A\varepsilon_0}{A\varepsilon_0} \\
\end{align}
$$

But we require

$$K_\mathrm{hyd} = \frac{\varepsilon_0 - \varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$$

Shouldn't this mean that $K_\mathrm{hyd}$ is actually proportional to a fraction containing the $1/\varepsilon$ values?

#### References

1. Greenzaid, P.; Rappoport, Z.; Samuel, D. Limitations of Ultra-Violet Spectroscopy for the Study of the Reversible Hydration of Carbonyl Compounds. *Trans. Faraday Soc.* **1967**, 63 (0), 2131–2139. DOI: [10.1039/TF9676302131](https://doi.org/10.1039/TF9676302131).

Comment: The assumption discussed by the paper (which they argue should be discarded because it is not a good one) is that the absorption of carbonyl species is independent of solvent.  That is the same as saying the concentration of _carbonyl_ is uniquely determined by absorbance.  The other assumption is that the only thing that affects absorbance of a compound is the extent to which its hydrated: hydrated carbonyls are assumed not to absorb at all, and _apparent_ per-molecule absorbance of carbonyl compounds in water is thus lowered by an amount proportional to the equilibrium constant.

Comment: Under those assumptions, there is no real difference between $A$ and $\epsilon$, they are both direct measures of the concentration of carbonyl in a solution.  They key is that the units of $\epsilon$ are L/mol/cm, where *mol* is mole of total carbonyl containing compound.

Answer (score 1):

The law is not as you state although it often gets reported as this. The '$A$' you quote is the optical density. The Beer-Lambert law is $I_{tr}=I_0e^{-\epsilon_\lambda [C]\ell}$ where $I_{tr}$ is the intensity of transmitted light for a molecule at concentration $[C]$ at wavelength $\lambda$ and cell path length $\ell$, and $\epsilon_\lambda$ is the extinction coefficient at wavelength $\lambda$.

From the definition you can see where the expression you ask about comes from even with their different notation; it looks as if $w=-{\epsilon_\lambda [C]\ell}$ where ${\epsilon_\lambda [C]\ell}$ is the optical density.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow. In your last equation, what is w, and why is it the negtative of the optical density? Additionally, doesn't it still imply that the extinction coefficient at a given wavelength is still inversely proportional to the concentration of the species? Working through the maths I get the relation:

(e(water, measured) - e0) / e0, where e0 is the extinction coefficient for the initial concentration and e(water, measured) is equilivent to eW in my post.

Comment: The equation you quote has $\epsilon^{+w}$ and from Beers law it should be $e^{-\epsilon [C]L}$ so $-w$, it may be my misunderstanding from what you wrote I has assume that it was a typo and $\epsilon^{w}$ should actually be $e^w$.

Comment: Ah that’s my fault - I didn’t define the terms in my equation because they were defined in the link. I’ve now edited it to make it more clear - the terms in the equation are all extinction coefficients; the W superscript says that they are the extinction coefficients in water solvent. This means when I wrote e in my first reply to you I meant epsilon, the extinction coefficients.

Comment: I realized that in my calculations I erroneously cancelled Ao and A with each other. Now working through the mathematics I can't seem to get the desired equation at all.